# imported function name is not visible in entities context

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework

I am working on silverlight application which uses EF. I am able to retrieve the data.  But I want to execute a stored procedure which returns no  value. I tried using Import function. and the function is created in DataModel.Designer.cs :

```
 public int ClearWorkflow(Nullable<global::System.Guid> processId)
        {
            ObjectParameter processIdParameter;
            if (processId.HasValue)
            {
                processIdParameter = new ObjectParameter("ProcessId", processId);
            }
            else
            {
                processIdParameter = new  ObjectParameter("ProcessId",typeof(global::System.Guid));
            }

            return base.ExecuteFunction("ClearWorkflow", processIdParameter);
        }
```

But the function name is not visible in entities context while accessing in silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

functions and procs are not supported in .net framework less than 4 
although they are appeared in 3.5 , they are not supported